# System of equation $x+y+z=2007; xyz=14000$

Tags: diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

> I have to solve the system of equations
>   $$\begin{cases}
> x+y+z=2008,\\
> xyz=14000,
> \end{cases}$$
>   where $x,y,z$ are positive integers such that $1\le x \le y \le z \le 2000.$

**My work so far:**

Let $P(t)=(t-2000)(t-7)(t-1)$ and $Q(t)=(t-x)(t-y)(t-z)$.

Then $P(t)-Q(t)=kt$. So $2000-z\ge 0 \Rightarrow Q(2000)\ge 0$

Comment: Do $x,y,z$ have to be integers? If so, please state it.

Comment: ... and if such is the case, begin by decomposing 14000 into primary factors...

Comment: ... then noticing that the given constraints imply that $\max(x,y,z)$ is quite large.

Comment: I  translated the problem into English. I suppose that $x,y,z \in \mathbb R$

Comment: No solution exists

Comment: If integers are only allowed

Comment: $x=1, y=7, z=2000$

Comment: @Roman83 That has $x+y+z=2008$.

Comment: If reals are allowed, then there are infinitely many solutions. You can pick one of $x,y,z$ arbitrarily (within a large range) and then solve for the other two.

Comment: @almagest : Ok. I will edit the condition

Comment: Is changing 2008 into 2007 a border effect of the translation into english ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: Yes :). 

In fact, the book has the answer $(1;7;2000)$

Comment: The condition $\leq 2000$ is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$14000=2^4\cdot 5^3\cdot 7$ has $40$ divisors, but just $36$ of them are $\leq 2000$ and just $6$ of them are between $\frac{2008}{3}$ and $2000$, namely $\{700,875,1000,1400,1750,2000\}$. These values are the possible values for $z$. For instance, $z=2000$ leads to the solution $x=1,y=7$. $z=1750$ does not lead to integer solutions, neither they do $1400,1000,875$ or $700$. So $\color{red}{(1,7,2000)}$ is the only solution.